# Reactions of tin (IV) iodide with potassium iodide and water

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides

In the reaction of tin (IV) iodide in acetone and water, the solution turns a urine yellow.

Is this simply due to the hydrolysis of tin (IV) iodide:

$$\ce{SnI4 + 2H2O -> SnO2 + 4HI}$$

why is the acetone needed though?

and for the reaction with $\ce{KI}$:

$$\ce{SnI4 + KI -> ?}$$ 
I understand it forms iodine, but what happens to $\ce{Sn}$ and $\ce{K}$ - do they react with the acetone for instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If iodide is oxidized to iodine (the cause of the yellow color), then something needs to be reduced in turn. Potassium is already in its most stable oxidation state (+I), so tin will be reduced, from $\ce{Sn}$(IV) to $\ce{Sn}$(II).

$$\ce{SnI4 + 2H2O -> SnO2 + 4HI}$$

$$\ce{SnO2 + 2HI -> I2 + SnO + H2O}$$

With $\ce{KI}$, a [yellow-brown solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lugol%27s_iodine) of $\ce{KI3}$ will be formed, which contains the [triiodide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triiodide) anion $\ce{I3-}$.

$$\ce{I2 + KI -> KI3}$$

When acetone is added, the yellow color of $\ce{I2}$ will slowly disappear as iodoacetone and $\ce{HI}$ are formed in an acid-catalyzed reaction ([source](http://mhchem.org/222/pdfLabs222/KineticsPartI.pdf)):

$$\ce{(CH3)2CO + I2 -> CH3C(O)CH2I + HI}$$