# How to get tin(II) oxide from tin(IV) oxide?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis

How to get $\ce{SnO}$ from the deposited $\ce{SnO2}$? Any method is ok.

If just heat the $\ce{SnO2}$, can it change to $\ce{SnO}$?

Comment: No, it won't react at all - SnO2 is thermally stable.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments and the other answer that $\ce{SnO2}$ is thermally stable and it is in fact $\ce{SnO}$ that thermally disproportionates to $\ce{SnO2}$ and most of the synthesis involves tin(II) salts e.g. [tin(II) oxyhydroxide](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020169314007300). However, there is a way to synthesize it from a tin(IV) salt. If you hydrolyze tin(IV) iodide, it forms tin(IV) oxide and hydroiodic acid which will then react with each other to form tin(II) oxide and iodine.

$$\ce{SnI4 + 2H2O -> SnO2 + 4HI}$$

$$\ce{SnO2 + 2HI -> I2 + SnO + H2O}$$

(taken from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/21597/17368). Upvote that answer also if you like this answer)

Answer (score 3):

Common ways of preparing tin monoxide ($\ce{SnO}$) all involve using another tin(II) compound as a precursors, such as reacting a tin(II) salt solution with sodium hydroxide. Not only does attempting to heat $\ce{SnO2}$ to decomposition fail; it is actually the $\ce{SnO}$ that decomposes with heating, disproportionating to give $\ce{SnO2}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_oxide.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is apparently a possible yes, but not precisely "just heating", as correctly noted by my esteem colleagues.

Per this 2008 source: ["Experimental study of SnO2/SnO/Sn thermochemical systems for solar production of hydrogen](https://aiche.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/aic.11584), to quote:

> The thermal reduction of tin(IV) oxide occurs in the temperature range 1400–1600°C following a zero order kinetic law of Arrhenius with an activation energy of 394.8 kJ mol−1... The operating conditions that prevent gaseous stannous oxide (SnO) from recombining with O2 are defined. The effect of a quenching device (water-cooled finger) is negligible whereas operation at low total pressure or low O2 and SnO partial pressures leads to nearly pure SnO product.

So, a high temperature treatment of tin(IV) oxide to stannous oxide is apparently possible under select operating conditions. In particular, low oxygen concentration and low $\ce{SnO}$ partial pressures may be able to produce a relatively pure $\ce{SnO}$ product.